# Webcam not working nor detected

Tags: webcam, 14.10

I recently bought Acer Aspire E3-111-C10N (8GB version), and to my surprise webcam is not working.

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 0f23 (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f48 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4a (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4c (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 0f12 (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0489:e078 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How you see, linux is not detecting my webcam, so do you have any ideas?
And yes, Cheese, GTK UVC and Skype also cold not reach my webcam.

Comment: you got a defective piece. get it replaced

Comment: but I need this netbook, might it be the driver/kernel problem?

Comment: You can try opening the netbook and verifying whether all the connections are properly made. My best guess is that the webcam cables come under the keyboard. Try removing the keyboard and secure all the connections. This might void your warranty. Hence the simplest is to get it replaced under warranty. Apparently service guys do check the cable connections before replacement.

Comment: I called the service and the guy told me it might be hardware problem, but Acer will accept my application only when I prove this problem under Windows. So I have to install Windows only because Acer doesn't support Linux service. Well played Acer and Microsoft, well played...

Comment: that happened to me as well. been there. hate it. but have to do it.

Comment: @aveemashfaq Could you please explain why you think the laptop/webcam is broken and need replacing? I'd say that a missing/incompatible driver is more likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did how the service guys told me: install Windows and original drivers dedicated for Windows (which comes on a DVD disc, but obviously E11 doesn't have a CD/DVD drive).

Acer service simply doesn't support Linux, so they can't told if the hardware is broken or not.

After installing proper drivers the webcam under Windows doesn't work either.

But it hasn't been a 10 days since I bought this netbook so I get replaced it with a new one.

Thanks for some nice ideas folks. I would never have guessed that it might be a hardware problem.